# HI I'm getting an error when using break function

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

**My code:**

```
import math
import sys
 
def addition():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one + two)

def Subtraction():
    one = int(input('What is your first number ? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one - two)

def Multiplication():
    one = int(input('What is your first number ? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one * two)


def Division():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    print(one / two)
    
def Modulo():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one % two)

calc_run = True
while calc_run == True:
    def calc_run():
        op = input('Do you want to add,subtract,multiply,divide, modulo or quit. ')
        if op == 'add':
            addition()
        elif op == 'subtract':
            Subtraction() 
        elif op == 'multiply':
            Multiplication() 
        elif op == 'divide':
            Division()
        elif op == 'modulo':
            Modulo()   
        elif op == 'quit':    
            print("Thanks for using this app")
            sys.exit
            break    
    calc_run()
```

***The Error:***

```
'break' outside loop
```

***The code worked when I tried this:***

```
import math
import sys
 
def addition():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one + two)

def Subtraction():
    one = int(input('What is your first number ? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one - two)

def Multiplication():
    one = int(input('What is your first number ? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one * two)


def Division():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    print(one / two)
    
def Modulo():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one % two)

calc_run = True
while True:
    def calc_run():
        op = input('Do you want to add,subtract,multiply,divide, modulo or quit. ')
        if op == 'add':
            addition()
        elif op == 'subtract':
            Subtraction() 
        elif op == 'multiply':
            Multiplication() 
        elif op == 'divide':
            Division()
        elif op == 'modulo':
            Modulo()   
        elif op == 'quit':    
            print("Thanks for using this app")
            sys.exit
            calc_run = False
    calc_run()
```

- I use Python 3.8 32bit

Comment: There's no loop inside `calc_run` function. So, `break` construct is not required.

Comment: @Balaji Ambresh 
I needed `calc_run` in the loop so I don't want to run the program again and again.

So how do I break the loop using break function???

Comment: `break` is statement, not function. Please post **full** error message. It is a `SyntaxError`, evaluated before any code is executed, so `sys.exit` is irrelevant.

Comment: Why do you create `def calc_run` inside the loop in the first place? Just remove that, put the code directly inside the loop without a function wrapper.

Comment: @TonnyStark if you do not want to run the code again and again, then do not write the program such that it runs again and again (again and again defining `calc_run` function inside `while True` cycle, doing nothing else)

Comment: OK Thanks All. 

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected.
Tested on Python 2.7.

```
import math
import sys
 
def addition():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one + two)

def Subtraction():
    one = int(input('What is your first number ? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one - two)

def Multiplication():
    one = int(input('What is your first number ? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one * two)


def Division():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    print(one / two)
    
def Modulo():
    one = int(input('What is your first number? '))
    two = int(input('what is your second number? '))
    print(one % two)

calc_run = True
while calc_run == True:
    op = raw_input('Do you want to add,subtract,multiply,divide, modulo or quit. ')
    if op == 'add':
        addition()
    elif op == 'subtract':
        Subtraction() 
    elif op == 'multiply':
        Multiplication() 
    elif op == 'divide':
        Division()
    elif op == 'modulo':
        Modulo()   
    elif op == 'quit':    
        print("Thanks for using this app")
        #sys.exit
        break
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo 
 
For fun 

Comment: @TonnyStark It will be more fun and nice if you actually said what's wrong with the answer so the poster can fix it

Comment: Checked on my laptop and updated post with full code. Try it out.